# Reinstall OS X due to compromised OS X partition whilst keeping Boot Camp

Tags: install

I have an iMac with OS X and Windows 7 dual boot (which was installed via Boot Camp). Recently, the OS X partition has been compromised, but the Windows one works great. I have created a bootable USB with OS X Snow Leopard and I want to reinstall OS X. I have 2 questions: Will I lose any personal data after reinstalling OS X? And will Windows 7 still work after reinstalling OS X considering that it has been installed through Boot Camp?

Comment: What to do you mean by compromised? Do you mean the file system has been corrupted and can not be repaired? Or something less serious like you deleted all your apps.

Answer (score -1):

You can reinstall your Mac OS. **It will not loss your data** which stored in your partition **until you not format your drive**. For reinstalling your Mac Os **no need to format drive**, just install new Mac Os into same partition and it will overwrite it. For that **i am sure**.

But regarding Boot Camp - window OS, i am not sure as i have not used boot camp for dual boot. I am aware of it. I think it will work. But make sure before go with it.

Comment: The Windows Boot Camp partition is completely independent. You could erase your OS X partition and Windows would be not be effected.